# Android Hilt cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. in repository Interface Class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, interface, repository, dagger-hilt

I'm getting this error ***error: [Dagger / MissingBinding] com.eduramza.domain.repositories.RemoteRepository cannot be provided without an @ Provides-annotated method.*** when implementing my repository interface with android hilt.

That's because my useCase implements my repository interface. What may be wrong with my implementation, below is the code:

app.Viewmodel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RemoteListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCase: GetTickersUseCase
    ): ViewModel() {
}
```

domain.usecase:

```
class GetTickersUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteRepository: RemoteRepository)
    : SingleUseCase<MainCoins> {

    override suspend fun executeCall(): Flow<Result<MainCoins>> = remoteRepository.readAllTickers()

}
```

domain.repository:

```
interface RemoteRepository {
    suspend fun readAllTickers(): Flow<Result<MainCoins>>
}
```

core.repositoryImpl:

```
class RemoteRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService: BraziliexService,
    private val tickersMapper: TickersMapper
) : RemoteRepository{

    override suspend fun readAllTickers(): Flow<Result<MainCoins>> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

core.module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class RemoteModule {

@Binds
abstract fun bindRemoteRepository(
    remoteRepositoryImpl: RemoteRepositoryImpl
    ): RemoteRepository
}
```

My multimodule app in this structure
[image]
where core implement domain, and app implement both.

why is the bind method not being initialized?

[image]

Comment: you are expecting a `RemoteRepository` to provide a `RemoteRepository` . You need expect `BraziliexService` and `TickersMapper` instances to create a `RemoteRepository` . Also Is there a need to have `RemoteRepository` of Activity Scoped it can be of Singleton Scope i guess.

Comment: And please post the whole dagger code for all dependency and try with my answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You using the  ActivityComponent but the RemoteRepository is the indirect  dependency of ViewModel so it should be tied with the ViewModel Lifecycle

so instead of **ActivityComponent**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class RemoteModule {

@Binds
abstract fun bindRemoteRepository(
    remoteRepositoryImpl: RemoteRepositoryImpl
    ): RemoteRepository
}
```

Use this **ViewModelComponent**

```
@Module
    @InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
    abstract class RemoteModule {
    
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindRemoteRepository(
        remoteRepositoryImpl: RemoteRepositoryImpl
        ): RemoteRepository
    }
```

Comment: Yes! ViewModelComponent was the solution! thanks!